# Automator looping variable number of times

Tags: automator

I've made a workflow that uses a loop and is designed to be called from an application. The problem I'm having is that sometimes I'll want the loop to run 10 times, and sometimes I want it to run 25 times. I have a variables set to the number of times the loop needs to run, but I can't put that in the text field for the number of times the loop should run. Can this be done, or is there an alternate way of accomplishing this?